# Saving large files sent from .Net in PHP through PUT or POST method

Tags: php, .net, file-upload

I am having trouble in saving a large file ~200MB and above sent through desktop application made in .Net framework and receiving the file in PHP. The desktop application sending the file through `writeStream` function of .Net.

**Problems:**
1) I am getting the data in PHP but the final file size exceeds the original file size. For example if the file size is of 36MB the file PHP saves will be of 55MB.
2) And the file also get corrupted after saved on server.

**Requirements:**
1) I need to save a large file sent from .Net to PHP with any method that is working.
2) Any working example of the problem will be highly appreciated.

**Note:**

I am making a Dropbox like application. I hope this will give you a general idea of what kind of application I need to make.

**PHP Code**

/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
            $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

```
        /* Open a file for writing */
        $fp = fopen($targetDir.$fileName, "a");

        /* Read the data 1 KB at a time
           and write to the file */
        while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)){
            fwrite($fp, $data);
        }         

        /* Close the streams */
        fclose($fp);
        fclose($putdata);
```

Comment: Show some code and we might be able to help.

Comment: I have edited my question with PHP code.

Comment: If you read from stdin a file that was POSTed there, it will probably be BASE64 encoded. That explains the size difference.

Comment: It is not POSTed it is PUTed.

Comment: Still. Check the resulting file. It will probably be BASE64 encoded.

Comment: We are not encoding the stream in Base64.

Comment: Then what is the 19 extra MB you are saving?

Comment: Yes you were right about base64 encoding. Let me try this.

Comment: Now the size have decreased from 55MB to 38MB. But still the file is not opening. Here is my new code:  **$targetDir = FCPATH.'uploads/';
  /* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
   $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
   
   /* Open a file for writing */
   $fp = fopen($targetDir.'testingzzz', "a");
   
   /* Read the data 1 KB at a time
      and write to the file */
   while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024*1024)){
    fwrite($fp, base64_decode($data));
   }**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42195/discussion-between-aleem-ahmad-and-bart-friederichs)